# Remove/Replace A Fragment from the Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a problem and I am stuck as to how to implement the following structure:

```
class A extends FragmentActivity{
   //In this I click a button which loads a fragment say class B
}

class B extends Fragment implments Interface{
    //This has a button which opens up an activity of list view say class C

  function replaceFragment(){
      try{
        FragmentManager fm = B.this.getFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_frame, new D()).commit();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.v("error",""+e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}

class C extends Activity{
   //It has an async task which loads something when the list view is clicked
  //The async task onPostExecute calls back the class B interface function

  onPostExecute(){
    callback.replaceFragment();
  }
}
```

Now when the interface function is called I want to replace the fragment B with another fragment say D which has its own layout. Can anyone help me in giving this suggestion or the solution to the problem I am having?

Another method I thought was instead of calling the callback function I would start class A all over again and changing the fragment to D when it gets loaded, but then the previous class A wasn't removed off the stack and when I press back I get the class A fragment activity again and this is causing a problem. Need a solution as I am stuck badly in this.

Answer (score 0):

When interface function is called, you can replace the existing `Fragment` with `Fragment D` as follows

```
Fragment d = new D();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, d).commit();
```

`R.id.frame_container1` is the ID of the `FrameLayout` where you add/replace youre fragments

Comment: Thanks for your reply but then I am calling the interface function from C right? So, if I define the callback function in B and write the code you have given then R.id.frame_container will not be found as it is in the view of A not in B.

Comment: I have put in some code in my function definition. Please see and let me know if I am doing something wrong in my code coz it always goes to the catch section when I try to replace the fragment.

Comment: What exception you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling [replace](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment%29) in your interface call back. I think this should work well.

Comment: I have put in some codes in my question that I tried but while replacing the fragment it always goes to the catch section. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.